# Duplicated objects created by jquery function

Tags: jquery

I made a custom jquery function autoSuggest that should create a div with menu for input field.

Then i want to apply it to a multiple fields, but when i do so it creates multiple divs, which is fine. Problem is that all they have the same id. That i wanted to be unique.

```
function randomString(length, chars) { 
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() *     (chars.length - 1))];
    return result;
}

$.fn.autoSuggest = function(){
    var id = randomString(16, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');


    if(!$('#autoSuggest_'+id).length) {
        $(this).offsetParent()
        .append('<div id="autoSuggest_'+id+'">content</div>');
    }


var autosuggestDiv = $('#autoSuggest_'+id);
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to use IDs?

Comment: yes, cause this pulls up different data depending on id

Comment: i would want it to only append div with same ID once

Comment: I still don't see why you need the id. Couldn't you keep track of a reference to the object or traverse from the input to the div?

Comment: Ya using any kind of transversal method would be better imho and as suggested by @JasonP. You don't really need IDs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over the input object. You can do this using `$(this).each(...)` or if the `this` object is already a jQuery object you can just use `this.each(...)`. (Thanks to @A. Wolff for that).

Try this:

```
$.fn.autoSuggest = function() {

   return this.each(function() {
        var id = randomString(16, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');

        if(!$('#autoSuggest_'+id).length) {
            $(this).offsetParent()
                .append('<div id="autoSuggest_'+id+'">content</div>');
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: `this` is already jQuery object, btw to keep chaining, you should return it: `return this.each(...);` anyway +1